# Write a `subString()` function

Tags: c, string

> Write a function called subString() to extract a portion of  a character string. The function should be called as follows
>
> ```
> subString (source, start, count, result);
> ```
>
> Where source is the character string from which you are extracting the substring, start is an index number into source indicating the first character of the substring, count is the number of characters to be extracted from the source string, and result is an array of characters that is to contain the extracted substring.

Here is what I have so far. I'm getting a weird result when I run the program

```
#include <stdio.h>

char substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
int i;
    source[start] = result [0]; // set the initial value of the result array     to the value of the source array at the point of 'start'
    
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++, start++) {         // keep adding to start     until 'result' has obtained all the values it was supposed to get from the     source array
        source[start] = result[i];
    }
    result [count+1] = '\0';    // adds a null terminator to the end of the resultant string
    return *result;
}

int main (void)
{
    char source [] = "Any help would be appreciated. I dont know where I've gone     wrong"; // define a generic string for the user to extract a string from
    int start = 0, count = 0;
    char result [255];


// allows for multiple different calls to be made without having to adjust the code every time
    printf("%s",source);

    printf("\n\nAt what point in the above statement should extracting begin? "); // assigns a starting point
    scanf("%d", &start);

    printf("\n\nHow many characters do you want to extract? "); // sets a number of characters to extract
    scanf("%d", &count);

    substring (source, start, count, result); // call the substring function

    printf("\n\nThe resultant string, after extraction is: %s\n\n", substring); // print the result of the subString function

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `source[start] = result[i];` are you sure?

Comment: `source[start] = result [0]` - this means you're overwriting the source with the results. Did you perhaps want to go the other way around? And as others have pointed out, perhaps the prototype for your function should be `char *substring(char source[], int start, int count, char result[])` although I'd really expect it to be `char *substring(char *source, int start, int count, char *result)`. Best of luck.

Comment: A tip: Use comments to describe "Why" you do something, not to paraphrase the code. Then they might actually become useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is an organized enumeration of problems with your code

1. You are passing the function name to `printf()`. Which indicates that it was a bad function name choice, you should pass `result` instead of `substring`.
2. You are returning only the first character of `result` in the `substring()` function.
3. Your function is using the uninitialized array `result` as the source string, which is incorrect, you need to copy the string from `source` to `result` instead.

This is a suggestion

```
char *substring (char *source, int start, int count, char *result)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0 ; ((i < start) && (source[i] != '\0')) ; i++)
        result[i] = source[i];
    for ( ; source[i + count] != '\0' ; i++)
        result[i] = source[i + count];
    result[i] = '\0';

    return result;
}
```

i think it's easy to understand what this function does.

**VERY IMPORTANT**: In c arrays are indexed from `0` to `N - 1` so be careful with `for` loops.

Comment: I adjusted the code to pass `result` , but how do I go about returning the whole string of `result` in the `substring()` function?

Comment: well, you are returning it by it's first element. Whole string can be recognized, because of '\0' after last character of string.

Comment: After compiling and including the most recent edit from your answer, I didn't get any bizarre results, but the function didn't start copying from the `start` point. Rather, it just copied the whole `source` string as the `result` string

Comment: What are the values you passed as `start` and `count`?

Comment: i passed 5 and 5 as `start` and `count`. I chose those arbitrarily

Comment: @AdityaP what output did you expect?

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work, using some of the help from above, but also with a good amount of my own thinking. Thanks for the help everybody

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *substring (char *source, int start, int count, char *result)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < (count) ; i++) 
        result[i] = source[i + start]; // after hitting start, as long as you're not at the end, the result should match the source
    result[i] = '\0';

    return result;
}
int main (void)
{
    char source [] = "character"; // define a generic string for the user to extract a string from
    int start = 0, count = 0;
    char result [255];

printf("%s",source);

printf("\n\nAt what point in the above statement should extracting begin? "); // assigns a starting point
scanf("%d", &start);

printf("\n\nHow many characters do you want to extract? "); // sets a number of characters to extract
scanf("%d", &count);

substring (source, start, count, result);

printf("\n\nThe resultant string, after extraction is: %s\n\n", result); // calling result, not the whole function

return 0;
}
```